# Unable to get object in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

The following parameter is defined in the model

```
public required object Signals { get; set; }
```

Data is transmitted to it:

[image: Data is transmitted to it]

But I get this error:

> The Signals field is required

[image: But I get this error]

I tried removing `required` and doing `object?`, it still didn't help, why is this happening?

Comment: Why use an required object? define a class which specify properties of what you require

Comment: looks like an int... maybe try: public int Signals { get; set; } ?

Comment: @pcalkins I do not know what data can come, so I wanted to mark them with this type.

Comment: Hi @WebFR, any update here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can custom model binding to bind the int type data to the object type property.

Model

```
public class Test
{
    public required object Signals { get; set; }
}
```

Custom Model Binding:

```
public class ObjectModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Signals");

        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            var model = new Test() { Signals=null};

            if (int.TryParse(valueProviderResult.FirstValue, out int intValue))
            {
                model.Signals=intValue;
            }
            else
            {
                model.Signals = valueProviderResult.FirstValue ;
                
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
    
public void Get([FromQuery,ModelBinder(typeof(ObjectModelBinder))] Test model)
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on above information.

You will have to add "?" in the controller methods signature.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string? id)
{
    return Ok(await _business.Get(id));
}
```

If not working can you share the signature method?
It seems that you are not calling the api properly.